# Почему не парсится конкретные id. Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautiful-soup

Подскажите, пожалуйста почему не парсятся конкретные `id`?

Код:

```
tag = links_match.find_all('div', {'id' : re.compile('g.*')})
```

При запуске `[]`.
Если на этом же сайте собирать любые другие `id`, то все ок. Пробовал собирать и маской и по точному вхождению, все равно `[]` на выходе.

Полный код:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re


html_open = urlopen('https://www.myscore.ru/snooker/').read()
links_match = BeautifulSoup(html_open, "lxml")

tag = links_match.find_all('div', {'id' : re.compile('g.*')})
print(tag)

with open('links_match_myscore.txt', 'w') as f:
    for item in tag:
        url = item.get('id')
        f.write('\n' + '\n' + str(url))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а не легче найти блок выше, и в нем найти все div с title подробности матча или другой параметр

Comment: если прописываю tag = links_match.find_all('div', {'title' : 'Подробности матча!'}) то на выходе тоже []. Или если ищу div по классу sportName snooker, в котором и находятся нужные div , то тоже не находит []

Comment: выведите soup в консоль и проверьте присутствует ли эти блоки в нем. Я почему то уверен, что сайт написан на javascript и bs4 в нем для парсинга бесполезен

Comment: подскажите, чем тогда лучше пользоваться? если bs4 не подходит

Comment: ну сначала проверьте не подгружаются ли эти данные через ajax, если нет, то selenium вам в помощь

Comment: да уже начал ставить, не знаете в чем может быть проблема? устанавливаю chromedriver, но при установке в командной строке выдает: Starting ChromeDriver 78.0.3904.105 on port 9515 Only local connections are allowed. Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.   И больше ничего не происходит. После теста webdriver.Chrome() ничего не происходит

Comment: зачем его устанавливать, это всего лишь драйвер для работы с браузером. Нужно на него ссылку указать и все

Comment: driver = webdriver.Chrome('\Desktop\Python\parser\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("https://google.com/"). Так например? все равно при запуске ничего не происходит, ошибки тоже нет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема в том, что эта страница уже изменена (вероятно она генерируется динамически), а ваши значения атрибута `id` уже не существуют.

Посмотрите, я немножко изменил часть вашей программы:

```
tag = links_match.find_all('div', {'id' : re.compile('g.*')})

with open('links_match_myscore.txt', 'w') as f:
    for item in tag:
        url = item.get('id')
        print(url)
```

и получил значения

> ```
> lsadvert-background
> project-debug
> lsadvert-right_zone_2
> userSettings
> lsid-remember-login-form-content
> ```

Все эти значения имеют букву `g`, но нет там значений типа `g15_xxxxxxxx`.